# YUI ajax set http header for basic authorization

Tags: http-headers, yui

How do I set http header for basic authorization using YUI connection manager ?

env: yui 2.8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Connect.html) is the best place to look for features not listed in the examples. (This is true of any library, not just YUI!)

The value for a [basic access authentication header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) should be a base 64 encoded concatenation of the username, a colon and the password.

You can include [this script](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html) to base64 encode.

```
var encoded = Base64.encode('yourUsername' + ':' + 'yourPassword');

YAHOO.util.Connect.initHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + encoded, true);
```